# Удалил файлы через revert git. Как вернуть?

Tags: git, git-revert

`git status`:

```
HEAD detached at 493151a  
Changes not staged for commit:  
  (используйте "git add/rm <file>...", чтобы обновить данные для закрепления)  
  (используйте "git checkout -- <file>...", чтобы отменить изменения в рабочей директории)

modified:   basic/composer.lock
modified:   basic/config/web.php
deleted:    basic/models/Prodaji.php
deleted:    basic/models/Rashodi.php
deleted:    basic/models/TovariVZayav.php
deleted:    basic/models/TovariVZayavSearch.php
deleted:    basic/models/Users.php
deleted:    basic/models/UsersSearch.php
deleted:    basic/models/Viruchki.php
deleted:    basic/models/ViruchkiSearch.php
deleted:    basic/models/Zajavki.php
deleted:    basic/models/ZajavkiSearch.php
modified:   basic/modules/MainManager/MainManager.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/controllers/ShopController.php
modified:   basic/modules/MainManager/controllers/TovariController.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/controllers/TovariVZayavController.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/controllers/UserController.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/controllers/ViruchkiController.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/controllers/ZajavkiController.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/models/Shop.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/models/ShopSearch.php
modified:   basic/modules/MainManager/views/default/index.php
modified:   basic/modules/MainManager/views/layouts/main.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/shop/_form.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/shop/_search.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/shop/create.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/shop/index.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/shop/update.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/shop/view.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/tovari-vzayav/_form.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/tovari-vzayav/_search.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/tovari-vzayav/create.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/tovari-vzayav/index.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/tovari-vzayav/update.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/tovari-vzayav/view.php
modified:   basic/modules/MainManager/views/tovari/_form.php
modified:   basic/modules/MainManager/views/tovari/_search.php
modified:   basic/modules/MainManager/views/tovari/create.php
modified:   basic/modules/MainManager/views/tovari/index.php
modified:   basic/modules/MainManager/views/tovari/update.php
modified:   basic/modules/MainManager/views/tovari/view.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/user/_form.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/user/_search.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/user/create.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/user/index.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/user/update.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/user/view.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/viruchki/index.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/viruchki/prodaji.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/zajavki/_addTovar.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/zajavki/_form.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/zajavki/_search.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/zajavki/create.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/zajavki/index.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/zajavki/update.php
deleted:    basic/modules/MainManager/views/zajavki/view.php
modified:   basic/views/layouts/main.php
deleted:    basic/web/css/test.css

Несопровождаемые файлы:  
  (используйте "git add <file>...", чтобы включить то, что должно быть закреплено)

basic/composer.json~

Нет изменений, добавленных в коммит (используйте "git add" и/или "git commit -a").
```

Файлов в проекте нету. Как мне их вернуть? Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написано же:

> используйте "git checkout -- <file>..." чтобы отменить изменения в рабочей директории

Answer (score 8):

## Если коммит еще не сделан

В этом случае коммит еще не сделан. Об этом можно узнать по сообщению:

> HEAD detached at 493151a
>   Changes not staged for commit:

### Полный откат

Можно просто [прервать `revert`](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) следующей командой:

```
git revert --abort
```

Она возвращает репозиторий к тому состоянию, которое было до начала revert.

### Частичный откат

Как предлагает Git и [подчеркивает участник pirj](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/364461/181472), можно отменить часть изменений, вносимых git revert, c помощью [команды `checkout`](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

```
git checkout -- <file1> <file2> <file3>
```

Это применимо к удаленным, измененным, переименованным и вновь созданным файлам, т.е. к любым изменениям от revert. Удобно, если вы хотите отменить какой-то коммит не полностью, но почти полностью.

## Если revert уже подтвержден коммитом:

Возможна и такая ситуация.

### Полный откат

Это частный случай [общего вопроса об откатах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431521/181472).

Чтобы вернуть всю рабочую директорию а также текущую ветку к состоянию, где файлы были:

1. Узнайте sha1 нужного коммита с помощью `git log` или `git reflog`.
2. Используйте [команду `reset`](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-reset):

   ```
   git reset --hard <commit-sha1-до-команды-revert>
   ```

### Частичный откат

Если вы хотите вернуть обратно только определенные файлы, то можете взять их из любой ревизии командой `checkout`.

```
git checkout <revision> -- <file1> <file2> <file3>
```