# Как вернуть файлы, затёртые манипуляциями в git?

Tags: git, git-revert

Всем привет!

После неосторожных движений в *git* (reset, revert, add -u) были удалены важные изменения. Откат через reset не помогает, изменения не появляются.

Что делать?

Comment: `add -u` не такое уж страшное действие )

Answer (score 2):

Все оказалось очень просто.

`git reflog` - находим хэш действия, до которого все было супер;
`git reset --hard [hash]` - жестко сбрасываем к этому действию.

Ответ нашел тут: [Удалил файлы через revert git. Как вернуть?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/364443/)

Comment: Добавлю, что это не подходит для ситуаций, когда вы уже запушили коммиты на сервер, где есть другие разработчики. Тогда придется делать `git revert [hash]`